# I have written an mp3 file to my database,and hosted the server,but in the response I am unable to see that file?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, ionic2

I have created the database and written the mp3 file in the db.Now I have created a server and used the router using express.But I am unable to see the response.It is displayed below.

[image: server hosted at localhost 8080/api/songs]

My code is as follows:

`server.js`

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var morgan = require('morgan');
    var bodyParser = require('body-Parser');
    var methodOverride = require('method-override');
    var cors = require('cors');

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/aHolyBoly');

    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cors());

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    });

    var Songs = mongoose.model('Songs', {
        title: String
    });


    app.get('/api/songs', function (req, res) {
        console.log("fetching songs...");

        Songs.find(function (err, songs) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)



            res.json(songs);
            //console.log('Songs',+JSON.stringify(Songs));
        });
    });

    app.listen(8080);
    console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

How can I see the response in the console.i.e my songs.mp3 file?

`storeAudio.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var fs = require('fs');
var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo=mongoose.mongo;


//establish mongoDB connection
 mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/aHolyBoly');
conn.once('open',function(){
   var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
 // var db = new mongo.Db('aHolyBoly', new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", 27017));
//var gfs = Grid(db, mongo);

var writeStream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename:'song1.mp3'
});
fs.createReadStream('../list/hero.mp3').pipe(writeStream);
writeStream.on('close',function(file){
    console.log(file.filename +'Written to db');
});
});
```

Points:
1.)I have stored the mp3 file in the database using gridFs-stream.

2.)Now I want to create an API so that I can host my server on it and my frontend uses that data with the help of API.

3.) The frontend will only fetch the data i.e) mp3 file.

Comment: What `type` is `songs` in the callback?

Comment: Do you want to print the binary data of `mp3` file?

Comment: yes, I want to get that data of mp3 file so that i can use that in my front end.I am following this tutorial. https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-review-app-with-ionic-2-mongodb-node/

Comment: You cannot send a binary data as a json, except if you base64-encode it, which does not sound like a good idea for a file larger than a few kb...

Comment: This is not a good idea. `mp3` files should be accessed using a cloud link.

Comment: Can I use the mp3 file directly with my frontend?I mean, I need to only fetch it with my frontend.@Tolsee, @Suhail Gupta

Comment: Providing your mongo-query is working your console.log will work if you stringify "songs" instead of "Songs". Variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: What I do not understand in your question is, your model definition states you only have one field that is `title` of type string but you are trying to get song.mp3?? How will that even be possible?? And another thing is that mongoose model constructor uses schema not just a json.

Comment: @AdityaJain Think it for once, what you are saying. Why are you storing it inside the mongodb?

Comment: I have got your point, I have edited my question once I have updated my storeAudio.js file also.Please once have a look.And I am using this first time, So please let me know where ever I have to make corrections.Actually, in the **tutorial** that I am following there models is used.I have got your point.@SuhailGupta, @Tolsee

Comment: @Tolsee In order to get the mp3 file, I should use here schema? and not the model?

Comment: No that is not what I am saying. Your model is created using schema not json as you are doing. I understood what your problem is, please give me some time to write a answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you must understand is when you use mongo's [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/), it will create two collection namely fs.files and fs.chuncks and what ever other models you created do not have your file rather what you can do is to link those files in your model. If you are willing(may be for now) to receive only one file that you have stored with filename song1.mp3 the below stated code will work for you. Hope this helps!

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-Parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise
var conn = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/aHolyBoly');


var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
Grid.mongo=mongoose.mongo;
let gfs;
conn.once('open', function () {
    gfs = Grid(conn.db);
});

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ 'extended': 'true' }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    //res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});


//song model should not be created like this

//var Songs = mongoose.model('Songs', {
 //   title: String
//});


app.get('/api/songs', function (req, res) {
    console.log("fetching songs...");
    
    //read from mongodb
    var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
         filename: 'song1.mp3'
    });

    // set response header
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    });
    readstream.pipe(res);
});

app.listen(8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");
```

To make clear on how linking a file to a model can be done, I have provided some code below:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose')
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema


 const UserFile = new Schema({
     username: { type: String, unique: true}
     file: { type: String }
 }) 


 // create the model to export 
 var UserFileModel = mongoose.model('UserFile', UserFile)

 module.exports = schemaModel
```

Suppose, you have stored a file for one user. And you stored that filename in file field of UserFileModel with the corresponding username. Then, you can easily get file of corresponding user in following route as below:

```
    var UserFileModel = require('path-to-UserFileModel');

    router.get('/api/user/file/:username', function (req, res) {

        UserFileModel.findOne({username: req.params.username}, function(err, doc){
            //read from mongodb
            var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({
                 filename: doc.file
            });

            // set response header
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            });
            readstream.pipe(res);
        })

    });
```

Comment: It is displaying following errors:
`C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server>node server.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.open (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:240:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:242:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\server.js:17:21)`

Comment: This time: `Error: Trying to open unclosed connection.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.open (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:240:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:242:47)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lenovo\aHolyBoly\server\server.js:17:21)`

Comment: If this route is not possible or we are unable to solve this, can you give some idea that you wrote in your answer about linking filename in the model.I think that can also work.

Comment: Please see the updated code its working now. Linking can be easy as storing a filename in your another model.